# Issue With Select Statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, select

I am trying to `select the top 1` of this select query then order `DESC`, every way I try, it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code:

```
SELECT '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),
CONVERT(MONEY, COALESCE(([amount]), 0)),
1) AS [Total]
FROM [myTable] a
left join [mySecondTable]  b on a.[ID] = b.[ID]
left join [myThirdTable c on c.[myNumber] = b.[myNumber]

WHERE c.[myName] = 'me'
```

If I wanted to select top 1 `amount` and then order by `amount` with `SELECT TOP 1` and `ORDER By [amount] DESC`, where would I put them exactly? Or this that even the correct way to do this?

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Top x goes right after the select keyword. And Order By goes at the end of your query.

Comment: Your query itself will return one `record` why do you need `Top 1` here

Comment: There will be 1 row in result. No need for `TOP`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I didn't mean to include SUM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ORDER BY will go at the end, and top 1 at the beginning.

```
SELECT top 1 '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),
CONVERT(MONEY, COALESCE(SUM([amount]), 0)),
1) AS [Total]
FROM [myTable] a
left join [mySecondTable]  b on a.[ID] = b.[ID]
left join [myThirdTable c on c.[myNumber] = b.[myNumber]

WHERE c.[myName] = 'me'
order by [AMOUNT] DESC
```

Comment: I found my issue, I was doing that, but I am changing Column name to TOTAL, so I need to order by TOTAL not AMOUNT